# Slot "0" games in Adventurers League games

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

When can I run a slot "0" adventure for the DMs in the convention I just organized?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to RPG.SE! By "Slot 0" do you mean "Session 0" where you gather all players together and discuss what kind of story do you want to play?

Comment: @Vylix: From my Googling, "Slot 0" has a special meaning as it relates to AL. The AL "DM Quests" document has a "Slot 0 DM" quest, with the following description: "Run a DDAL or DDEP adventure as a "Slot 0" table where all players at the table are preparing to DM the adventure at a convention or gameday, for a premiere, regional preview, or a new adventure released from the DMsGuild that month."

Comment: (That said, it's still not entirely clear to me what is being asked here. I'm not sure if that's just due to my lack of familiarity with AL and "slot 0" games.)